# How to get child's type in golang

Tags: go

I've been studying `Go` recently.
In the under sample, I got the type a, not b. Why?
And how do I get b?

```
// parent
type A struct {
    foo string
}

func (a *A) say() {
    // I want b here, not a
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(a).Type().String())
}

// child
type B struct {
    A
}

func main() {
    b := new(B)
    b.say()
}
```

Comment: Embedding is **not** inheritance. Thinking about parent/child or super/subclass relationships is not helpful at all. Stop that. `b.say()` is *nothing* but a shorthand notation for `b.A.say()`: The method `say` is always invoked on an `A`. What you try to do is impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You got always the A value because you have only one `say()` method which point to A struct.

So, when you apply the `say()` method to B struct, the compiler will look at B struct and its fileds in order to find if there is a `say()` method of B struct or there is any field of B struct who have a `say()` method.

In your case, B struct doesn't have any method which will point to it. But it have a field which cointain A struct and which have a `say()` method.

So, everytime you'll call the `say()` method within B struct, you'll call `B.A.say()` which will print the A value.

Otherwise, if you want to print B and A values, you can modify your code to something like this example:

```
package main
import (
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type A struct {
    foo string
}
// This method will point to A struct
func (a *A) say() {
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(a).Type().String())
}

type B struct {
    A
}
// This method will point to B struct
func (a *B) say() {
    fmt.Println(reflect.ValueOf(a).Type().String())
}

func main() {
    b := new(B)
    b.say()     // expected output: *main.B
    b.A.say()   // expected output: *main.A
}
```

Output:

```
*main.B
*main.A
```

You can also run this code with [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/iHagZljRWz)

Comment: Thx, i need to change my way of thinking